# Java String.replaceAll not affecting one .txt file

Tags: java

I am trying to replace a particular known string, of the form "$Variable", with another string in a few files. The operation works as expected for all the files except for the .txt file. In this file the replaceAll call appears to be completely ignored. Also Target is in regex form.
Here is the code snippet;

```
        try {
            Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
                @Override
                public FileVisitResult visitFile(Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
                    String sFile = file.getFileName().toString();
                    if (sFile.endsWith(".png") || sFile.endsWith(".jpg") || sFile.endsWith(".thmx")) {
                        return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                    }

                    Charset charset = Charset.forName("windows-1252");
                    String content = new String(Files.readAllBytes(file), charset);
                    content = content.replaceAll(target, replacement);
                    Files.write(file, content.getBytes(charset));

                    return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
                }
            });
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
```

I can't seem to figure out what is going on with this. I have .htm and .rtf files where this method works just fine but fails completely when it encounters the .txt file. Any suggestions or advice is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Perhaps the `.txt` file is stored in `UTF-16`, not `windows-1252`

Comment: I tried UTF-8 without luck, but I can try that as well.

Comment: Just to be sure, why don't you try to copy the contents into another file and save it with the `windows-1252` encoding? Open the file to see if something changed and try to run your program with that file.

Comment: @Andreas That did the trick. Man I was stumped with that one. Can you explain the reasoning behind this further because I couldn't understand why I could see the string (in debug mode) and see the target clearly but it wouldn't get replaced. Also is there a way to tell the character encoding being used by a file? Thank you for your help and quick response!

Comment: Unrelated to the core of the question, but here's a warning: You're checking for `.png`, `.jpg` and `.thmx`, but not confirming the file is `.txt`. Unless you're absolutely sure you will only *ever* deal with those formats in the file tree, you should add a check for `.txt` specifically. If not for the current version/file-tree, then in case the app or the file-tree gets altered in the future.

Comment: @XenoRo Thanks for the warning. I know the code is not robust but it honestly doesn't need to be at this point. I know exactly what files I'm working with. I added that portion to the code because those file types show up in the directory I'm working in and I didn't want to alter them in any way, everything else was fair game. I will probably change that in the future but for now it is not necessary.

Comment: In UTF-16, each (BMP) character is stored as a 2-byte (16-bit) Unicode value. Normal ASCII characters (00-7F) are the same in Window-1252 and Unicode, so when stored as UTF-16, the ASCII character 5A (`Z`) gets stored as bytes 5A 00 or 00 5A (depending on byte order). Your text file in UTF-16 is therefore twice as big as the same file in Windows-1252. When you read the UTF-16 file as Windows-1252, those 00 bytes are loaded as the NUL ASCII character, so "Hello" is loaded as "H<NUL>e<NUL>l<NUL>l<NUL>o<NUL>" and will of course no longer match your regex.